# RocketQuery.DumpRowIds No QueryResult object found

Tags: einstein-analytics

I am trying to create a filter node in dataflow with the below SAQL filter:

```
Date_Taken>='Unit.Unit.runcat_on_date'
```

Both are date fields from the same node.

I am encountering below error :

> RocketQuery.DumpRowIds No QueryResult object found.

Is there any other way to compare these fields ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a computeExpression beforehand. In it generate a Field with

```
case when Date_Taken>='Unit.Unit.runcat_on_date' then 1 else 0 end;
```

Then filter on that field.